# Adding new social network to socmed widget through PHP -- Wrong icon showing

Tags: php, widget, social-media, wordpress

Let me just apologize up front for my ignorance; I've never really seen PHP up-close and am really new to the Wordpress world...

I added a Pinterest option to a social media widget using this [tutorial](http://goo.gl/5CkjyF).  The addition worked, giving me a new Pinterest option in the widget.  The widget says 'Pinterest' on the dashboard side and links to Pinterest perfectly on the front end.

The problem is the site is displaying a Google+ icon instead of a Pinterest icon.  What's even weirder is that when you 'inspect element' the html is specifying the pinterest.png icon—but, of course, showing the Google+ icon.  All I can really do is scratch my head at this point…

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not even sure what I need to include here: the whole php file that I edited? a link to the site?  I'm happy to provide whatever I need to.

Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: Could you share a link?

Comment: Sure, vard. I'm assuming you're asking about a link to the site, so here you go: http://temp034-crystals.delarivadesign.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what's going on here is that the image is hidden on line 56 of `main-style.css`:

```
.social.social__row li.social_li a .social_ico img,
.social__list li.social_li a .social_ico img
{ display:none !important; }
```

And the Google+ icon is added via a pseudo element (`:after`) who get the Google+ image front an icon font:

```
.social.social__row li.social_li:last-child a .social_ico:after,
 .social__list li.social_li:last-child a .social_ico:after 
{ content:"\f0d5"; }
```

So what you need to do is to add an other css rule for your Pinterest icon, something like that :

```
.social.social__row li.social_li a.social_link__pinterest .social_ico img {
    display: block !important;
}
.social.social__row li.social_li:last-child a.social_link__pinterest .social_ico:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the Font Awesome Pinterest icon, delete the two lines we added before, and add this :

```
.social.social__row li.social_li:last-child a.social_link__pinterest .social_ico:after {
    content: "\f0d2";
}
```

Comment: vard, thanks a lot for your generous willingness to help.

So I've tried to add the rule that you've given above, but when I inspect the element the rule is rejected and the Google+ icon is still showing.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where did you added the rule? I can't see it in main-style.css.
Though it could be an inheritence issue, see the fixed rules.

Comment: Man, I am just not getting it.  Now I've got 2 icons showing.

Comment: All right figured, there was an error in the second rule. See updated answer. Should do the trick now.

Comment: I just saw that the icons are pulling from Font Awesome, and that all I did was upload a png.  That would also explain why my pinterest icon doesn't have the transition effect.  How do I call up the Font Awesome Pinterest icon?  I know the problem here is just my own ignorance and I am really grateful to you for bearing with me.

Comment: All right if you want to use the Font Awesome icon, check on the updated answer. You just need to delete the two lines we added before and add this one - remove your current pinterest image too by the way.

Comment: For your information, if you need in the future to get the unicode of a Font Awesome icon, check on that website : http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/pinterest/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, vard.  I can't say thank you enough.  I wish there was a way I could repay you...

Comment: You're welcome, we're here to help ;) If the answer satisfied you, you can accept it by clicking on the check icon just at the left of it, that'll be enough for me ;)