# Font Awesome Pinterest icon stopped working

Tags: css, wordpress, unicode, font-awesome, social-media

A very helpful user just helped me resolve an issue a little earlier this morning (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483635/adding-new-social-network-to-socmed-widget-through-php-wrong-icon-showing)).  Just a few minutes later, however, the icon stopped working.  When I add the forward slash before the unicode, an empty box displays.  When I remove the forward slash, only the unicode number displays.  Any thoughts?

Comment: For whatever it's worth, by the way, I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Link us to an example of the problem, please.

Comment: Use a backslash, not a forward slash. Also, rather than linking to another question, please provide the code relevant to this particular problem in your question.

Comment: @Shaggy, here is my code: .social.social__row li.social_li:last-child a.social_link__pinterest .social_ico:after { content: "f231"; } Also, so we're on the same page, / = backslash, \ = forward slash, right? Forward slash is called for for FA unicodes.  But I've tried both; backslash when added actually shows up with the unicode, forward slash causes empty box to display, and unicode number with no slashes causes the actual unicode number to display.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as you include the link to the FontAwesome CSS:

```
.pinterest:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f231";
}
```

Just change the CSS selectors to the elements you want. Keep in mind that CSS `content` only works on `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: Hey, Tugzrida.  Just now saw your response.  I did what you suggested, but still no luck.  I'm adding this to the custom css area in the WP theme's options area.  Interestingly enough, it doesn't seem to be saving the \ forward slash after I 'save options.'  I think I'll probably need to manually edit the styles.

Anyways, thanks again for the help, man.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but try `\\f321`. The first backslash then might pardon the second one.